# The purpose of type classes in Haskell vs the purpose of traits in Scala

Tags: scala, haskell, typeclass, traits

I am trying to understand how to think about type classes in Haskell versus traits in Scala.

My understanding is that type classes are primarily important at compile time in Haskell and not at runtime anymore, on the other hand traits in Scala are important both at compile time and run time. I want to illustrate this idea with a simple example, and I want to know if this viewpoint of mine is correct or not.

**First, let us consider type classes in Haskell**:

Let's take a simple example. The type class `Eq`.

For example, `Int` and `Char` are both instances of `Eq`. So it is possible to create a polymorphic `List` that is also an instance of `Eq` and can either contain `Int`s or `Char`s but not both in the same List.

My question is : **is this the only reason why type classes exist in Haskell**?

The same question in other words:

Type classes enable to create polymorphic types ( in this example a polymorphic `List`) that support operations that are defined in a given type class ( in this example the operation `==` defined in the type class `Eq`) but that is their only reason for existence, according to my understanding. Is this understanding of mine correct?

Is there any other reason why type classes exist in ( standard ) Haskell?

Is there any other use case in which type classes are useful in standard Haskell ? I cannot seem to find any.

Since Haskell's Lists are homogeneous, it is not possible to put `Char` and `Int` into the same list. So the usefulness of type classes, according to my understanding, is exhausted at compile time. Is this understanding of mine correct?

**Now, let's consider the analogous List example in Scala:**

Lets define a trait `Eq` with an `equals` method on it.
Now let's make `Char` and `Int` implement the trait `Eq`.

Now it is possible to create a `List[Eq]` in Scala that accepts **both** `Char`s and `Int`s into the **same List** ( Note that this - putting different type of elements into the same List - is not possible Haskell, at least not in standard Haskell 98 without extensions)!

In the case of the Haskell's List, the existence of type classes is important/useful **only** for type checking at compile time, according to my understanding.

In contrast, the existence of traits in Scala is important **both** at compile time for type checking and at run type for polymorphic dispatch on the actual runtime type of the object in the List when comparing two Lists for equality.

So, based on this simple example, I came to the **conclusion** that in Haskell type classes are primarily important/used at compilation time, in contrast, Scala's traits are important/used **both** at compile time and run time.

**Is this conclusion of mine correct?**

If not, why not ?

EDIT:

Scala code in response to n.m.'s comments:

```
case class MyInt(i:Int) {
  override def equals(b:Any)= i == b.asInstanceOf[MyInt].i
}

case class MyChar(c:Char) {
  override def equals(a:Any)= c==a.asInstanceOf[MyChar].c
}


object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
     val l1 = List(MyInt(1), MyInt(2), MyChar('a'), MyChar('b'))
     val l2 = List(MyInt(1), MyInt(2), MyChar('a'), MyChar('b'))
     val l3 = List(MyInt(1), MyInt(2), MyChar('a'), MyChar('c'))
     println(l1==l1)
     println(l1==l3)
  }
}
```

This prints:

```
true
false
```

Comment: Just a note, traits are useful in your use case of course, but you could even use abstract classes for that, the primary use of traits is __mixin-composition over inheritance__, because of the diamond problem you can't have multiple inheritance, but you can have multiple traits splitting the functionality and achieving traits reusability, you end up with some class which inherits behaviours form many traits.

Comment: you repeat quite a few points quite a few times...

Comment: I know but I try to be as clear as possible, I am sorry if the repetition makes the text slightly .... boring ?

Comment: It's worth noting that it's not just type classes that are only a compile time feature of Haskell; basically *all* type-level features are completely checked/resolved during compilation. Haskell's type system is based on quite a different "philosophy" of what types are.

Comment: "Let's define a trait". Please go ahead and define it, then proceed to define a list of whatever. You will quickly discover that you can't quite do that.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are hinting at n.m.. Could you please describe in more detail what you mean ?

Comment: I mean what I say, and I say that you cannot do what you have described in Scala. I invite you to try and actually do that and prove me wrong, or discover the reason why you can't do that. (This does not necessarily invalidate your question per se, only your example). Post compilable code.

Comment: Ok, I will try to do that.

Comment: @n.m. I tried to do what you suggested, I have included my attempt as en EDIT paragraph. It's not exactly the same what I wrote about in the original question but quite close to it: I do not explicitly define the Eq trait, I just reuse - for simplicity - Scala's Any abstract class (which is not a trait, indeed). I still hope though that the added Scala code clarifies the question somewhat.

Comment: Well, `Any` in Scala has `==` and `equals` but the types are very different from those found in Haskell. Doesn't matter, `Any` has `toString` which is similar to Haskell's `show`, and you can legitimately ask why you can't put many different `Show`-able things in a list (in Haskell98; you can do that with extensions). The answer is that you don't really need too; since the *only* thing you can do with a `Show`-able is `show`, you might just as well put the results of `show` (which are all `String`s) in the list. Haskell is lazy and so `show` will not be called until needed.

Answer (score 10):

I will comment on the Haskell side.

Type classes bring *restricted polymorphism* in Haskell, wherein a type variable `a` can still be quantified universally, but ranges over only a subset of all the types -- namely, the types for which an instance of the type class is available.

Why restricted polymorphism is useful? A nice example would be the equality operator

```hs
(==) :: ?????
```

What its type should be? Intuitively, it takes two values of the same type and returns a boolean, so:

```hs
(==) :: a -> a -> Bool         -- (1)
```

But the typing above is not entirely honest, since it allows one to apply `==` to any type `a`, including *function types*!

```hs
(\x :: Integer -> x + x) == (\x :: Integer -> 2*x)
```

The above would pass type checking if `(1)` were the typing for `(==)`, since both arguments are of the same type `a = (Integer -> Integer)`. However, we can not effectively compare two functions: well-known Computability results tell us that there is no algorithm to do that in general.

So, what we could do to implement `(==)`?

**Option 1**: at run time, if a function (or any other value involving functions -- such as a list of functions) is found to be passed to `(==)`, raise an exception. This is what e.g. ML does. Typed programs can now "go wrong", despite checking types at compile time.

**Option 2**: introduce a new kind of polymorphism, restricting `a` to the function-free types. For instance, ww could have `(==) :: forall-non-fun a. a -> a -> Bool` so that comparing functions yields to a type error. Haskell exploits type classes to obtain exactly that.

So, Haskell type classes allow one to type `(==)` "honestly", ensuring no error at run time, and without being overly restrictive. Of course, the power of type classes goes far beyond of that but, at least in my own view, they primary purpose is to allow restricted polymorphism, in a very general and flexible way. Indeed, with type classes the programmer can define their own restrictions on the universal type quantifications.

Comment: What did you mean by the following sentence. "The above would type if (1) were the typing for (==), since both arguments are of the same type a = (Integer -> Integer). "

Comment: @jhegedus I mean that the equality above would pass type checking: both arguments are of the same type `a = Integer->Integer`, so the polymorphic type for `(==)` can be instantiated with that `a`.